# Star rating plugin, how to put radiobutton values into an array?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I´m currently using the [Star Rating Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) for a project where I need users to assess their language skills. Basically they select a language and rate their skill from 1-5 using the Star plugin. Spring MVC is being used for backend.

The actual language is being posted as an array with parameter name "languages". I would also like to post the rating as an array, but my issue is that the Star Rating Plugin expects a different name for each group of ratings (in this case each language). So for now I have input parameters with name=star1, star2 etc.

I was thinking of using jQuery to put the values from star1, star2 etc into an array when the user submits the form, but I´m not sure how to do that. Is there any other way using "native Spring" that I could solve this problem?

Sample code below:

```
<form:errors path="languages" class="small"/></label>
  <form:input path="languages" class="reginput" id="language1"/>

  <div class="starinput">
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled" value="1" />
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled" value="2" />
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled" value="3" />
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled" value="4" />
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled" value="5"  checked="checked"/>
  </div>
  <br>

  <label> 
  <form:errors path="languages" class="small"/></label>
  <form:input path="languages" class="reginput" id="language2"/>

  <div class="starinput">
    <input name="star2" type="radio" class="star" value="1" />
    <input name="star2" type="radio" class="star" value="2" />
    <input name="star2" type="radio" class="star" value="3" />
    <input name="star2" type="radio" class="star" value="4" />
    <input name="star2" type="radio" class="star" value="5" />
  </div>
  <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="starinput">
    <input name="star[]" type="radio" class="star" value="1" />
    <input name="star[]" type="radio" class="star" value="2" />
    <input name="star[]" type="radio" class="star" value="3" />
    <input name="star[]" type="radio" class="star" value="4" />
    <input name="star[]" type="radio" class="star" value="5" />
  </div>
```

The `[]` will indicate it has to process the input as an array. All selected item values with the name `star[]` will than be placed into an array. So just use the same name everywhere and use a different value for each group.

Comment: Like my post says: "... but my issue is that the Star Rating Plugin expects a different name for each group of ratings (in this case each language). So for now I have input parameters with name=star1, star2 etc." If I use the same name (star[]), instead of two groups with five stars each I will get one group with 10 stars. Kinda wierd, but that´s how the plugin works.